# XSD choice inside sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I understand and use `xs:choice` and `xs:sequence` separately but I do not understand what `xs:choice` inside `xs:sequence` mean?

```
<xs:element name="sports-content">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="sports-metadata" />
        <xs:element name="sports-event" />
        <xs:element name="tournament" />
        <xs:element name="schedule" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Ok. This XML will be valid.

```
<sports-content>
  <sports-metadata />
  <tournament />
</sports-content>
```

Will this XML be valid or not?

```
<sports-content>
  <sports-metadata />
  <tournament />
  <sports-metadata />
</sports-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xs:sequence` element in your XSD is superfluous; it can be removed without affecting validity of any XML document.  An `xs:sequence` around an `xs:choice` would be useful, for example, if you wanted the choice to always be preceded or followed by one or more elements in sequence.

Yes, both of the XML documents in your question are valid against your XSD (and will continue to be if you remove the `xs:sequence` wrapper around `xs:choice`.